# Is to possible to read from cassandra cluster even at any node failure

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra cluster with 4 nodes, is it possible to read the data only from the available nodes, except the node that is down, is this possible? or is there any configurable property to handle this type of scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with replication, yes.  There are a few things you need:

- Set replication factor at least 2.  The more replicas, the more failed nodes you can cope with.  However, the more replicas you have the worse your performance is since more nodes duplicate the work.
- Choose an appropriate consistency level.  The consistency level (CL) determines how many nodes need to be involved with a read or write operation.  CL.ALL means use all replicas so you can't tolerate any failures.  CL.ONE means use just one node.  CL.QUORUM means a majority of replicas (RF/2+1)
- You can read and write data from any node, not just ones containing that data.  If you use a client library like Hector, you should tell it about all nodes and it will avoid ones that are down, as well as load balance amongst the available nodes.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can this consistency level is applicable for partition without replicas?

Comment: Without replication the consistency level is meaningless for reads (and mostly meaningless for writes, apart from CL.ANY) since all are equivalent.  If you don't have any replication then you cannot read the portion of data stored on unavailable nodes.  If you don't care about that and just want to ignore unavailable data then you just need to catch the UnavailableException you get when you make the query.